# Put a font-awesome icon inside an input tag

Tags: html, font-awesome

I'm trying to put a Font-awesome icon inside an input tag.

This is my `HTML` code:

```
<div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
</div>
```

But that icon is bigger than input box as you can see in this picture:

[image]

How can I fix the icon?

Comment: Did you try to set <span> or <i> font-size ?

Comment: No I did not try. What should I set?

Comment: Add a class to <span class="test"> and then try to play with .test class font-size. Something like this :  .test {font-size: 14px}

Comment: Adding fa-lg , fa-2x , fa-3x , ... class to <i> element is also doing that as well

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Bootstrap 3

Checkout the [Bootstrap examples](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#bootstrap) in the Font Awesome documentation:

```
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

It should work out of the box, so if you still have height differences, check that there is not other CSS stuff that override your `input-group-addon` height

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vs0wpy80

## Bootstrap 4

Bootstrap 4 introduced some [new classes for input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/), we need to use `input-group-prepend` and `input-group-append`:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8do9v4dp/5/

Comment: If these examples have worked I would not have posted the question

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that this solution no longer works for bootstrap4.0

Comment: @piotao I just added an example with Bootstrap 4 classes ;)

Comment: This example breaks if the form has a label

Answer (score 3):

```
input.form-control{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

In my case it helps

Comment: Thank you. I have spent a lot of time for this problem. Nice tip. It works.

Comment: It may work, but you are overriding Boostrap CSS, it will probably cause you some style issue on other inputs...

Comment: Yes, you're right. We can't use it straight in way I posted it, because we may broke layout. We have to provide precise selector to element which we override. I've just posted example how we can do it, without selector because I hadn't any markup.

Answer (score 1):

### With CSS only

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <input type="text" class="input">
   <i class="icon" class="fas fa-some-icon"></i>
</div>
```

Wrap the input and the icon in a 2 columns grid with this column template: 1fr 0

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 0;
}
```

Give the icon a relative position from the right:

```
.icon{
    width: 40px;
    position: relative;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Give the input a nice padding on the margin:

```
.input{
    padding-right: 57px;
}
```

The input will take 100% of the space in the grid and the icon will float atop.

Works well with responsive designs and you can click on the icon.